# Pedestrian argument

Tags: traduction, expressions-idiomatiques

Je cherche des équivalents français à l'expression *"pedestrian argument/method"*. Il s'agit d'une utilisation dans un contexte scientifique, où on parle d'une alternative simple et fiable, même si moins rigoureuse, aux méthodes plus sophistiquées, demandant plus de travail et/ou de connaissances théoriques.

Comment: At least in math, a pedestrian method is not any less rigorous than a non-pedestrian method.

Comment: Have you looked in a monolingual English dictionary? pedestrian means: sans imagination.

Comment: @Lambie This is also a possible interpretation. Note that English is not my first language - I mention in the comment to Gilles' answer the original expression, but it would be even harder to explain.

Comment: Merriam Webster: Definition of pedestrian (Entry 1 of 2)
1: COMMONPLACE, UNIMAGINATIVE
his sentences and phrases are too often pedestrian, commonplace, and flat
— The Times Literary Supplement (London) [The other meaning is piétonnier/aire.

Comment: @Lambie another way I would say it : "it's not very cool/sexy, but it works"

Comment: That is slang, your question isn't. But I guess anyone who married Brigitte Bardot would know that.

Comment: I know that a *pedestrian argument* has a special meaning when used in a maths demonstration but since I am not a science person I will abstain from answering. Not everyone on FL having the scientific background to understand the phrase I'd like to point to two answers on maths.stackexchange that use the phrase. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1365572 and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1615822

Answer (score 2, accepted):

J'ai déjà vu « démarche pédestre ». C'est identique étymologiquement au *pedestrian* anglais, et le sens est en gros le même. Mais c'est beaucoup plus rare en français.

Le [Trésor de la langue française](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/p%C3%A9destre) définit *pédestre* dans ce sens comme

> Par métaphore. [En parlant du style] Simple, sans affectation.

On trouve l'expression sur le web dans des contextes divers, mais seulement un très petit nombre d'instances. Ce n'est pas une expression courante.

> il faut bien utiliser la démarche "pédestre"   ([forum de physique](https://forums.futura-sciences.com/physique/611717-mesure-de-sx-2.html), France, 2013)

> Rares sont les candidats qui y parviennent par la démarche pédestre et sûre proposée dans le texte.   ([rapport de concours de physique](https://www.doc-solus.fr/prepa/sci/adc/pdf/rapports.pdf/2003/MP_PHYSIQUE_X_2_2003.rapport.pdf), France, 2003)

> On développe une démarche pédestre, en allant pas à pas dans la difficulté.   ([cours d'analyse de données](https://git.lab.sspcloud.fr/celinetecher/2021-06-funathon2/-/blob/master/Sujets/Sujet%202/Sujet_2_R.Rmd), ?, 2021)

> avec notre démarche pédestre et sans fracas, nous faisons en somme plus de chemin et de besogne que nos concurrents   ([essai](https://laporteouverte.me/2014/02/20/le-pouvoir-de-limagination-chez-les-enfants/), France, 1904)

> La démarche pédestre sans l'outil de l'idéal était une démonstration que l'on pouvait faire en terminale C en 1971.   ([discussion en ligne sur les mathématiques](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discussion:Construction_des_nombres_r%C3%A9els), France, 2016) (l'idéal est un concept mathématique avancé par rapport au niveau considéré)

Une démarche pédestre n'est pas moins rigoureuse qu'une démarche plus sophistiquée, au moins en mathématiques. Elle est plus laborieuse.

Je ne me souviens pas avoir entendu « argument pédestre » (pour lequel Google ne trouve qu'[une unique utilisation](https://bf.wikiqube.net/wiki/Proofs_and_Refutations) dans ce sens sur le web, ni « argumentaire pédestre », ni « argumentation pédestre » (je suis apparemment le premier à écrire ces deux expressions sur le web), ni « raisonnement pédestre » (3 occurrences [1](http://www.numdam.org/article/ASENS_1970_4_3_4_385_0.pdf) [2](https://fr.tax-definition.org/49018-pedestrian) [3](https://in.b-ok.as/book/4456432/fea0ea)). On ne peut donc vraiment pas dire que l'expression est commune.

Dans un contexte scientifique j'aurais plutôt tendance à parler de « raisonnement **élémentaire** » (ou d'« approche élémentaire », « méthode élémentaire », etc.). Le sens est très voisin mais parfaitement identique : dans les deux cas il s'agit d'éviter des outils sophistiqués, mais « pédestre » implique un côté laborieux alors que ce n'est pas le cas pour « élémentaire ». S'il faut traduire « *pedestrian method* » en conservant le côté laborieux, je proposerais plutôt « méthode élémentaire laborieuse ».

Comment: Merci. Pour plus de contexte : en russe je dirais "la méthode des travailleurs et paysans" - une expression empruntée du discours communiste, comme l'opposé "des aristocrates et la bourgeoise"

Comment: pedestrian is just a fancy adjective. a pedestrian argument is not a "thing". It is someone just writing what they think using that term.  And it's definitely not élémentaire. It means dull and boring, A dormir debout, en language courant.. The OP says the context is science, but, quite frankly, it could be any intellectual endeavor.

Comment: Si je considère cette phrase "Can anyone help with an elementary proof" prise d'une [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1615806) de maths.stackexchange et cette autre : "This is a bit of a pedestrian argument, but you asked for one" prise dans la [réponse](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1615822) qui lui est faite, je trouve que *élémentaire* (dans le sens du mot qui veut dire « d'une simplicité relative ») convient parfaitement pour cette expression imagée qui n'a pas vraiment d'équivalent en français.

Answer (score 1):

Je ne connaissais pas l'expression *pedestrian argument* et j'aurais d'abord pensé à des piétons qui se disputent ;-)

Quand à *démarche pédestre* proposé ailleurs, pris au sens propre, ça ressemble à un pléonasme... (*Démarche*: Manière de marcher, *Marcher*: Aller d'un endroit vers un autre en faisant une suite de pas à une cadence modérée, *Pédestre*: Qui se pratique à pied.)

D'après ce que je comprends de la description donnée dans la question, il pourrait s'agir d'une « méthode [empirique ».

[TLFi : Empirique](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/empirique).

> Qui ne s'appuie que sur l'expérience.
>
> 1. [Dans quelque domaine que ce soit, en parlant d'une méthode ou d'un mode de connaissance]

Après plus d'explications sur l'expression attendue, une autre suggestion pourrait être « **méthode très [terre-à-terre](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/terre-%C3%A0-terre)** ».

> TLFi
> **2.** *Loc. adj.* Qui a rapport aux préoccupations matérielles, aux réalités quotidiennes au concret; qui manque d'élévation, de hauteur de vues.

**Terre-à-terre** est une traduction de *pedestrian* attestée dans le Harrap's Standard (merci @None) et le [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/pedestrian), et **empirique** est donné comme quasi-synonyme de *terre-à-terre* par [wikipedia](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/terre-%C3%A0-terre).

Comment: Non, *empirique* serait un contresens. Une méthode empirique n'est pas rigoureuse. Une “pedestrian method” peut l'être.

Comment: Effectivement, c'est assez précis, même si un peu formel.

Comment: @Gilles Je me suis appuyé sur la définition de l'OP.

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' Peut-on alors parler de méthode 'mécanique', parfois laborieuse, similaire à une ligne droite alors que d'autres méthodes empruntent des raccourcis pour arriver au résultat?

Comment: @vc74 Non, ça serait différent. « Mécanique » a en général l'implication qu'il suffit de suivre une règle bien établie et qu'il n'y a pas de difficulté. Une méthode mécanique n'est pas laborieuse. Et par ailleurs une méthode mécanique peut utiliser des outils sophistiqués, du moment qu'il suffit de les appliquer sans devoir comprendre comment ils marchent. Et en plus en physique on pourrait comprendre qu'il s'agit d'un raisonnement de mécanique par opposition à statique, thermodynamique, etc.

Comment: « Terre à terre » est effectivement assez similaire, bonne idée. (To Anglophones: this is roughly equivalent to “down to earth”.)

Comment: « terre à terre  » est une des traductions attestée (Harrap's Standard) de l'emploi adjectival de *pedestrian*.

Answer (score 1):

J'ai deux propositions à faire :

- **rudimentaire** : qui signifie simple et peu outillé et donc laborieux (mais qui pourra donner des résultat avec de la patience et du travail).

Cela me semble bien s'appliquer pour une méthode. On pourrait parler d'une *méthode rudimentaire mais efficace*.

- **de bon sens** : se rapproche de "terre à terre" mais me semble plus naturel à l'oral notamment. C'est la façon de penser intuitive des gens qui ont les pieds sur terre (voir le fameux bon sens paysans).

Cela s'appliquerait bien à un *argument de bon sens* ou *un raisonnement de bon sens*.